# Scala. foreach in one element Lists of Dates

Tags: list, scala, date, foreach, jodatime

I want to create a function that works on a single date or over a period of time. For that I make a list of strings like this:

```
import com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports._
val fromDate = "2015-10-15".toLocalDate
val toDate = "2015-10-15".toLocalDate
val days = Iterator.iterate(fromDate)(_ + 1.day).takeWhile(_ <= toDate).map(_.toString)
```

Now I want to access days content:

```
scala> days.foreach(println)
2015-10-15

scala> days.foreach(day => println(day))
```

With the first foreach I get the only element in days list, but with the second I get nothing. This is just a sample, but I need to use the 2nd form, because I need to use day value inside the function.

If I use a range both methods work like they are supposed to...

Anyone knows why this behaviour?

Thanks in advance!

P.D. I don't want to use another method to create the list of strings (unless I can't find a solution for this)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Second function works in same way as first.

You've created `Iterator` object, which you can *iterate* only once.

To be able use it any amount of times just convert you iterator to list.

`val daysL = days.toList`

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. V. I dindn't know that "feature" of Iterators. As you can guess, I'm fairly new to Scala.